# How to update dynamically the tooltip of a Google Visualization chart after being initialized?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

The graph is rendered when the page loads. Then, a socket sends data to update column by column. With this, visually the data is updated correctly because the column grows but the tooltip always shows zero.

See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sw2mq7Lq/1/

```
function example_callback(){
  window.data_table_chart_receivable.setValue(1,1,10000); /* Bars graph */
  window.data_table_chart_receivable.setValue(1,2,10000); /* Line graph */
  window.data_table_chart_receivable.setValue(1,3,10000); /* Tooltip */

  window.chart_receivable.draw( window.data_table_chart_receivable, window.options_chart_receivable );
}
```

The *example_callback()* is simulating data inserted after the page load, inserting data for the column *Nov*. The column visually is different from zero but the tooltip still shows zero.

And the column Feb that is inserted in the page load shows correctly the tooltip.

How I can update the value of the tooltips after being initialized?

Inspecting in Chrome shows that the value is updated to 100000, but the format is not updated and still shows $ 0.00:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tooltips display the *formatted value*, so you just need to re-format the data.

See example (from provided fiddle)...

```js
function draw_chart_receivable() {
  var data_table = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  data_table.addColumn({"type":"string","label":"Mes"});
  data_table.addColumn({"type":"number","label":"Ventas"});
  data_table.addColumn({"type":"number","label":"Ventas"});
  data_table.addColumn({"type":"number","role":"tooltip"});

  data_table.addRow([{v: "2015-10-01", f: "Oct"}, {v: 0.0}, {v: 0.0}, {v: 0.0}]);
  data_table.addRow([{v: "2015-11-01", f: "Nov"}, {v: 0.0}, {v: 0.0}, {v: 0.0}]);
  data_table.addRow([{v: "2015-12-01", f: "Dic"}, {v: 0.0}, {v: 0.0}, {v: 0.0}]);
  data_table.addRow([{v: "2016-01-01", f: "Ene"}, {v: 0.0}, {v: 0.0}, {v: 0.0}]);
  data_table.addRow([{v: "2016-02-01", f: "Feb"}, {v: 22609.45}, {v: 22609.45}, {v: 22609.45}]);
  data_table.addRow([{v: "2016-03-01", f: "Mar"}, {v: 0.0}, {v: 0.0}, {v: 0.0}]);

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({decimalSymbol: ".", groupingSymbol: ",", prefix: "$ "});
  formatter.format(data_table, 1);
  formatter.format(data_table, 3);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_receivable'));

  options = {fontSize: 14, height: 320, width: "100%", colors: ["#e7e7e7","#95d600"], animation: {duration: 1000, startup: true, easing: "out"}, chartArea: {width: "100%", height: "80%"}, hAxis: {baselineColor: "#CCCCCC", textStyle: {color: "#999999"}}, vAxis: {baselineColor: "#CCCCCC", textPosition: "none", ticks: [0,22609], gridlines: {count: 0}, gridlineColor: "white"}, legend: {position: "none"}, tooltip: {textStyle: {color: "#95d600", fontSize: 12}}, seriesType: "bars", bar: {groupWidth: "90%"}, series: [{enableInteractivity: false, tooltip: "one", dataOpacity: 0.4},{type: "area", lineWidth: 3, pointSize: 10, dataOpacity: 0.7}], hasCurrency: true}

  chart.draw(data_table, options);

  window.options_chart_receivable = options;
  window.data_table_chart_receivable = data_table;
  window.chart_receivable = chart;
  window.formatter = formatter;

  example_callback();
};

google.load('visualization', '1.0', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: draw_chart_receivable});

function example_callback(){
  window.data_table_chart_receivable.setValue(1,1,10000);
  window.data_table_chart_receivable.setValue(1,2,10000);
  window.data_table_chart_receivable.setValue(1,3,10000);

  // re-format data
  window.formatter.format(window.data_table_chart_receivable, 1);
  window.formatter.format(window.data_table_chart_receivable, 3);

  window.chart_receivable.draw( window.data_table_chart_receivable, window.options_chart_receivable );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_receivable"></div>
```

You could also use `setFormattedValue` but then you would need to perform the formatting manually...

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I need